Using two "by" categories in tbl_summary from gtsummary in R
I would like to create summary table using two "by" factor (age category and gender)
i would like to obtain this table. Any ideas?
I tried
data %>% select(Sex, Age, Height, Weight, BMI, MET) %>% 
     mutate(Age_cat = case_when(Age < 30 ~ '18-29 years',
                                Age < 40 ~ '30-39 years',
                                Age < 50 ~ '40-49 years',
                                Age < 80 ~ '50-70 years')) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = Age_cat,
    digits = everything() ~ 1, 
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{median} ({p25} – {p75})",
  ) %>% bold_labels() %>% 
  add_overall()

but i dont know how to include also gender.

tbl_strata() might help you here

Hi Tamara, if you edit your question to include a snippet of your data (e.g. the output of dput(head(data)) people will be able to give you better advice.
